# What is the necessary and sufficient condition for a CW-complex to have its homology groups torsion-free?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

> What is the necessary and sufficient condition for a CW-complex to have its homology groups torsion-free?

*Definition* from Wikipedia: An abelian group $A$ is called **torsion-free** if every element of $A$ except the identity is of infinite order.

Examples:

1. $H_i(S^n)=\mathbb{Z}$ if $\in \{0, n\}$, $H_i(S^n)=\mathbb{0}$ if $i \notin \{0, n\}$, so all its homology groups all torsion-free.
2. Projective space, $H_0(\mathbb{R}P^2)=\mathbb{Z}$, $H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)=\mathbb{Z_2}$, $H_i(\mathbb{R}P^2)=0, i>1$. The first homology group is not torsion-free.

When reading Wikipedia, it said that the orientability of the projective spaces is obvious from its homology groups. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space#Homology

*Question*: Is the orientability the necessary and sufficient condition for a CW-complex to have its homology groups torsion-free? If not which direction is implied and what other condition would be sufficient and necessary?

Comment: What's your definition of orientability of a cw-complex?

Comment: @user17786 I thought there was a standard definition of orientability. Looking at wikipedia, they define orientability for manifolds and surfaces without the generality. So there is no general definition for orientability?

Comment: I don't know about it. Here Hatcher says that he neither doesn't know about notions of orientability for general simplicial complexes: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23713/simplicial-complexes-vs-geometric-realization-of-abstract-simplicial-complexes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned above, there is no standard notion of "orientability" for CW-complexes.  I will assume you meant manifolds instead.

- The open Möbius band is a nonorientable manifold.  It has the homotopy type of a circle, hence its homology groups are free abelian.
- Let $M$ be a compact, non-orientable $n$-manifold.  By Poincaré Duality, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-Poincaré Duality and the Universal Coefficient Theorem, both $H_1(M,\mathbb{Z})$ and $H_{n-1}(M,\mathbb{Z})$ have nontrivial $2$-torsion.
- $\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^3$ is orientable but has first homology group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.
- A nonorientable manifold admits a connected $2$-sheeted **orientation covering**.  In particular its fundamental group admits an index $2$ subgroup, so for instance any simply connected manifold must be orientable.  This does not mean that there must be an order $2$ element in the fundamental group of a nonorientable manifold: e.g. it follows from basic group cohomology that the fundamental group of any manifold with contractible universal cover -- so in particular, every nonorientable closed surface other than the projective plane -- has torsionfree fundamental group.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the assertion in wikipedia, recall that a compact connected manifold (without boundary) of dimension $n$ is orientable if and only if the top homology group $H_n(X;\mathbb Z)\cong \mathbb Z$ (see in Hatcher's *Algebraic topology* the section entitled *Orientations and homology*, chapter 3.3).

Comment: That's true, but if it's nonorientable $H_n(X,\mathbb{Z}) = 0$.  Either way it's torsionfree.

Comment: My answer was regarding the assertion of wikipedia, not the question itself, which was properly answered by yourself. I just had the feeling that the question linked that assertion with the torsion in homology, and wanted to show that they have nothing to do.